# Quebrar linha depois da tag <img> com RegEx

Tags: php

Colegas.

Não tenho muito conhecimento com expressões regulares, porém preciso com que depois da tag < img > quebre uma linha. Por ex.:

> $string = "< img src='imagens/imagem.jpg' > aqui haverá a quebra de linha";

Ficaria dessa forma:

> (a imagem) 
> aqui haverá a quebra de linha

Comment: Olá Bacco... quase o mesmo caso. Usei o seu exemplo anterior e funcionou perfeitamente, consegui tirar a tag [caption], mas agora o texto tem uma imagem e no retorno aparece a imagem e ao lado os textos. Gostaria que depois da imagem, houvesse a quebra de linha, para que os textos ficassem abaixo da imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue a RegEx:

```
preg_replace( '/(<\s*img.*>)/U', "$1<br>\n", $string );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/vzxC5L)**.

Só fico preocupado em estar ajudando você a fazer o site complicar à toa, pois a causa do problema parecem ser os dados no DB num formato inadequado.

Fica a sugestão de tratar os dados ao gravar no DB, e não na hora de mostrar na tela. Melhor ainda seria se você fizesse uma marcação especial para suas postagens, e criasse já as tags e o layout à partir daí (como faz o Markdown, por exemplo).

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado mais uma vez Bacco pela ajuda. Na verdade estamos mudando o sistema, tirando o WordPress e criando outro. O problema é que o cliente quer manter as notícias cadastradas anteriormente pelo WP e são mais de 800 rs rs rs..

Comment: Nada impede você de criar um script para "consertar" estas noticias persistas no banco, não é necessário fazer isso no braço.

Comment: Exato, como o @mauhumor disse, você pode, em vez de usar essas técnicas para mostrar os dados na tela, mudar as postagens antigas programaticamente, assim fica com tudo no padrão novo, sem perder as antigas. Por exemplo, em vez de fazer o PHP mudar os dados no echo, faça o PHP regravar as postagens antigas num campo novo do banco.